# SEC EDGAR API to Google Sheets integration

Tags: json, api, google-sheets, edgar, sec

I want to connect US Securities and Exchange Commission (SEC) API to Google sheet. I want to be able to upload files in JSON from SEK server to Google Sheets directly. Buy could not make any of ImportJSON functions work. It gives me 403 code error. I know that the issue has something to do with credentials/headers, as it was discussed here:
[How to get data from SEC Edgar python and a json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73862886/how-to-get-data-from-sec-edgar-python-and-a-json/73863738#73863738)

But IDK how to implement that in Google Sheet.

Here is the page for the SEC API just in case:
https://www.sec.gov/edgar/sec-api-documentation

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar problem, trying to pull data in to a spreadsheet via an API.
The best way to do this would be to write a script (in python for example) to pull and parse the JSON data, create a data table, and then export that table to a CSV. This stackoverflow question shows really well how to get the JSON.

[Accessing filing data from SEC EDGAR API in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74929749/accessing-filing-data-from-sec-edgar-api-in-python)

If you absolutely must start from a Google sheet, then this video does a great job of explaining how to use code from within a Google sheet to pull the JSON data and put it in to the sheet.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wySqfG5ztQc

Use the video to set everything up, edit the code from the first link, and you should be good to go.